# How to create spark sql table for a large json table faster

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I tried using the following SQL to create a table from json files

```
create table tmp.pg_tbl_report_group_data using json 
location '/rawdata/json/tbl_report_group_data';
```

It works but when the data is large, it becomes very slow. I thought (maybe it's wrong) spark scan all the data to infer the schema, so I tried then

```
create table tmp.pg_tbl_report_group_data (

    report_key string,
    unique_report_key string,
    field string,
    value string,
    type bigint,
    ids array<bigint>,
    sql string,
    create_time timestamp,
    update_time timestamp,
    unique_key string

) using json 

location '/rawdata/json/tbl_report_group_data'
```

This SQL runs very faster, however, when I query using

```
select * from tmp.pg_tbl_report_group_data limit 10
```

all columns in result rows are null;

My root question is to create a table from a large json dataset fast. The way to specify columns manually or to speed up the phrase of inferring schema or any other is welcome.

edit1:

Tried `samplingRatio 0.0001`, still slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm who post the question. In fact, `timestamp` in our json are formatted as float number. then change `create_time`, `update_time` type to double can resolve this problem.